# Simple Linear Regression Error no matching methods

Tags: julia, glm

I am attempting to mess around with a simple autoregressive model and need to perform a simple linear regression in julia and am running into an issue that says

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fit(::Type{LinearModel}, ::Matrix{Float64}, ::Matrix{Float64}, ::Nothing)
```

My code is

```
using XLSX, DataFrames, GLM, StatsBase
Quakes = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("/Users/jjtan/Downloads/QUAKE.xlsx", "quakes"))
for i in 1:98
    Quakes[!, Symbol("t", i)] = [zeros(i); Quakes[1:end-i, :x]]
end
ols = lm(@formula(x ~ t1), Quakes)
```

Note that

> typeof(Quakes)

returns a DataFrame 99x99

I have additionally tried the documentation regression to ensure that everything is working properly ie

```
using DataFrames, GLM
data = DataFrame(X=[1,2,3], Y=[2,4,7])
ols = lm(@formula(Y ~ X), data)
```

Which has produced the expected

```
StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Vector{Float64}}, GLM.DensePredChol{Float64, LinearAlgebra.CholeskyPivoted{Float64, Matrix{Float64}, Vector{Int64}}}}, Matrix{Float64}}

Y ~ 1 + J

Coefficients:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                 Coef.  Std. Error      t  Pr(>|t|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)  -0.666667    0.62361   -1.07    0.4788   -8.59038    7.25704
J             2.5         0.288675   8.66    0.0732   -1.16797    6.16797
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I have tried changing the variables to call using df.var notation as well as :var notation to no avail. I am quite confused as to why with pretty much identical lines of code one is running into an error and the other is not.

Comment: I can't really replicate the error, looking at the method error it looks like the might be an issue with the columns of the DataFrames, you should be able to check them using `typeof.(eachcol(Quakes))` this could be a lead as to where the error is.

Comment: More specifically, the error you're seeing is telling you that your `x` variable in `x ~ t1` is a matrix, when it should be a vector - you can get the same error when you do e.g. `lm(rand(5, 2), rand(5, 1))` as opposed to `lm(rand(5, 2), rand(5))`. I'm not sure why you would end up with a matrix when passing a formula + DataFrame to `lm`, so we'e need to see `first(Quakes, 5)` to say more.

Comment: I read the error and thought that that was weird as well. `first(Quakes, 5)` yields what one would expect though notable perhaps is the datatype under the variables are "any" and not "Float64" or other. Maybe that is creating the error? `typeof.(eachcol(Quakes))` yields all Vector{Any} types... Using StatsBase I was earlier having issues with the `autocor` function where Vector{Any} would not work as an argument for the expected AbstractVector{T} could that potentially be the source of error? I solved it by changing to Vector{Float64}

Comment: I had a similar error with my dataFrame. the columns types were "Any". converted to numeric type like  Int64 or Float64 and the error is resolved